# How to Check if debug is "off" or "on" in c?

Tags: c

For my program there is a section where I need to know whether the program is in debug mode or not. I googled it and I couldn't find how I could achieve it through c. Does anyone have an idea how I can do it?

The program is school project where I use signals and increment numbers.  Here is what is says for debug mode:

> When debugging is "on", your program should report the total every  seconds (using `alarm()`) and ignore SIGUSR1. When debugging is "off" the alarm() should be turned off and your program should handle SIGUSR1 as before (i.e. report on the status of total). SIGINT should cause your program to report the running total and then terminate.

Comment: please define "Debug mode". Are you using something like #DEFINE DEBUG

Comment: The C language itself has no concept of "debug mode", other than the `NDEBUG` macro that you can define or undefine to affect the behavior of the `assert()` macro (that's probably not what you're referring to). Many development environments do have such a concept. You'll need to tell us which one you're using.

Comment: (curious) Why would you want to know this for only a "section" section of your program ? 
Normally, a program is either fully compiled/linked in DEBUG (contains debugging information, no optimization) or in RELEASE (no or minimal debugging info. and optimizations)

Comment: The program is school project where i use signals and increment numbers. here is what is says for debug mode: "When debugging is "on", your program should report the
total every <arg3> seconds (using alarm()) and ignore SIGUSR1.
When debugging is "off" the alarm() should be turned off and your program should handle SIGUSR1 as before (i.e. report on the status of
total). SIGINT should cause your program to report the running total
and then terminate."

Comment: I wasnt sure how to check whether the program is running in debug in a way that if(true) then it will start the timer and alarm after every arg3 second.

Comment: @user2872131, with that assignment, I would use an environment variable or an argument to indicate debug mode. Perhaps `NDEBUG`, but I've bad experience with tracing code not compiled in when I needed it, surely not tying it to the generation of debug information or the level of optimization.

Comment: @Max, my experience is that most "debug" executable have the debug information for only part of the code (third party libraries are often without it, and often even internal libraries).  And some compilers don't tie the presence of debugging information to the lowest level of optimization (but it can be harder to use due to the de-structuring effect of optimization).

Comment: @AProgrammer thank you for your suggestion I did see it when i was looking online though I wasnt sure what it exactly was but I will try to figure it out and look into the `NDEBUG`.

Comment: Ok, if I understand, the "debug" mode that we are talking about is some sort of a "log" that you can turn on or off ?

Comment: You should _not_ be using NDEBUG for things it's not meant for. What if you want your own debugging active but still want asserts deactivated? Use your own environment variable if you wish to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

C itself has no concept of debugging mode other than the `NDEBUG` flag for controlling `assert()` calls.

Hence, you're probably talking about something you need to build in yourself.

The easiest way to do that is probably just to provide a global variable containing the debug state (initialised to false) and then set it or clear it at relevant times.

For example, this code segment would use a command line argument to set debugging on if the first argument to the program is `-d`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int debugging = 0;  // init to false

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if ((argc > 1) && (strcmp (argv[1], "-d") == 0))
        debugging = 1;
    printf ("Debugging is %s\n", debugging ? "on" : "off");

    // rest of program.

    return 0;
}
```

The `debugging` variable, being global, is available anywhere in the code so you can access, set or clear it at will.

You can even set or clear it within the interrupt service routines, so sending signals to the program from outside could change its state.